# How to tile the same image repeatedly in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, aspect-ratio, editing, resize, grid

How to tile a 1:1 image 3 times horizontally, side-by-side 1:3, without having to manually calculate and type in 3 times the width of the original as a new file? And without being constrained to absolutely 3 times the width of the original, but fit to your own specified target width for the new 1:3 file so that they fit seamlessly, while retaining the target 1:3 aspect ratio?

Finally, how to instead tile the same image 9 times repeated in a 3:3 grid? Steps on how to do these in Photoshop or Darktable could helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With Gimp

### Computing sizes

In the Gimp entry fields for numbers, you can enter simple formulas. So you don't need to compute `1200*3` manually on the side, you just enter `1200*3` in the input field, and Gimp will set the field to 3600.

A special case of this is of course to do `Image > Canvas size` and add a `*3` at the end of the horizontal/vertical size fields.

### Replicating/tiling a picture

If the picture is under 1000*1000px:

1. Create/open the target image, set its canvas size if necessary, add a layer if necessary, etc...
2. In the "tile" picture, do `Select > All`, `Edit > Copy` to copy the picture to the clipboard
3. In the Bucket-fill tool, set the options to:

   - Fill whole selection
   - Pattern fill
   - Click the pattern icon and select the "Clipboard" pattern (this is always the first in the list, so the top left corner in the mosaic of patterns)
   - Bucket-fill

Instead of creating a new image you can of course change the canvas size of the current one, copy the existing layer to the clipboard, add a new layer, make sure it is as big as  the canvas, and then bucket-fill.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tile filter for this.

1. While the image is open, go to `Filters > Map > Tile`. The image
   height/width is already shown.
2. Just multiply either the height or width by 3. The other dimension would automatically be multiplied as the aspect ratio is fixed.
3. Click OK, that's it

If you want the tile as a separate image the check "Create new image"
If you want different repetitions for vertical and horizontal, unlink the aspect ratio. Multiply width and height by the desired number of repetitions.

[image: Tile dialog]